# How to make buttons unique in pygame?

Tags: python, button, pygame

I am creating Battleship in pygame for a class right now and I am trying to go above and beyond because I like using python and creating things with it with pygame. Anyways, I have created a Button class and it works just fine except for one problem, if I have more than one button on a screen they all run the same code :/ I need them to be unique and run different code when they are clicked and I can't seem to get that done lol.

Here is the button class:

```
import pygame

red = (255, 0, 0)
darkRed = (153, 0, 0)
green = (0, 204, 0)
darkGreen = (0, 102, 0)
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
gray = (192, 192, 192)
darkGray = (96, 96, 96)


class Button(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

def __init__(self, color, color2, value):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.color = color
    self.color2 = color2
    self.value = value

    self.image = pygame.Surface([80, 50])
    self.image.fill(self.color)

    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

def update(self):
    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    xPos = self.rect[0]
    yPos = self.rect[1]
    width = self.rect[2]
    height = self.rect[3]

    if xPos + width > pos[0] > xPos and yPos + height > pos[1] > yPos:
        self.image.fill(self.color2)

    else:
        self.image.fill(self.color)

def click(self):
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if click[0] == True:
        return self.value

    else:
        return False
```

Here is the main code that runs everything:

```
from Button import *
from TextDisplay import *
from wallPositions import *

screen_width = 800
screen_height = 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))


def screen0():
pygame.init()

button_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

button = Button(green, darkGreen, True)
button_list.add(button)

text = Text("Battleship", white, 115, (screen_width * .5), (screen_height * .5 - 50))

done = False

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

button.rect.x = (screen_width * .5 - 35)
button.rect.y = (screen_height * .5 + 70)

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        if button.click() == True:
            screen1()

        button_list.update()

    screen.fill(black)

    text.draw(screen)

    button_list.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(30)

pygame.quit()


def screen1():
pygame.init()

button_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

button = Button(gray, darkGray, 1)
button_list.add(button)
button.rect.x = x_list[4]
button.rect.y = y_list[2]

button2 = Button(gray, darkGray, 2)
button_list.add(button2)
button2.rect.x = x_list[6]
button2.rect.y = y_list[2]

button3 = Button(gray, darkGray, 3)
button_list.add(button3)
button3.rect.x = x_list[8]
button3.rect.y = y_list[2]

button4 = Button(gray, darkGray, 4)
button_list.add(button4)
button4.rect.x = x_list[10]
button4.rect.y = y_list[2]

button5 = Button(gray, darkGray, 5)
button_list.add(button5)
button5.rect.x = x_list[4]
button5.rect.y = y_list[4]

button6 = Button(gray, darkGray, 6)
button_list.add(button6)
button6.rect.x = x_list[6]
button6.rect.y = y_list[4]

button7 = Button(gray, darkGray, 7)
button_list.add(button7)
button7.rect.x = x_list[8]
button7.rect.y = y_list[4]

button8 = Button(gray, darkGray, 8)
button_list.add(button8)
button8.rect.x = x_list[10]
button8.rect.y = y_list[4]

button9 = Button(gray, darkGray, 1)
button_list.add(button9)
button9.rect.x = x_list[4]
button9.rect.y = y_list[8]

button10 = Button(gray, darkGray, 2)
button_list.add(button10)
button10.rect.x = x_list[6]
button10.rect.y = y_list[8]

button11 = Button(gray, darkGray, 3)
button_list.add(button11)
button11.rect.x = x_list[8]
button11.rect.y = y_list[8]

button12 = Button(gray, darkGray, 4)
button_list.add(button12)
button12.rect.x = x_list[4]
button12.rect.y = y_list[10]

button13 = Button(gray, darkGray, 5)
button_list.add(button13)
button13.rect.x = x_list[6]
button13.rect.y = y_list[10]

button14 = Button(gray, darkGray, 6)
button_list.add(button14)
button14.rect.x = x_list[8]
button14.rect.y = y_list[10]

button15 = Button(red, darkRed, True)
button_list.add(button15)
button15.rect.x = x_list[12]
button15.rect.y = y_list[10]

instructions = Text("Select your row and column then hit 'Fire!'", white, 30, (screen_width * .5), 20)

text = Text('1', black, 50, (button.rect.x + 40), (button.rect.y + 25))
text1 = Text('2', black, 50, (button2.rect.x + 40), (button2.rect.y + 25))
text2 = Text('3', black, 50, (button3.rect.x + 40), (button3.rect.y + 25))
text3 = Text('4', black, 50, (button4.rect.x + 40), (button4.rect.y + 25))
text4 = Text('5', black, 50, (button5.rect.x + 40), (button5.rect.y + 25))
text5 = Text('6', black, 50, (button6.rect.x + 40), (button6.rect.y + 25))
text6 = Text('7', black, 50, (button7.rect.x + 40), (button7.rect.y + 25))
text7 = Text('8', black, 50, (button8.rect.x + 40), (button8.rect.y + 25))
text8 = Text('1', black, 50, (button9.rect.x + 40), (button9.rect.y + 25))
text9 = Text('2', black, 50, (button10.rect.x + 40), (button10.rect.y + 25))
text10 = Text('3', black, 50, (button11.rect.x + 40), (button11.rect.y + 25))
text11 = Text('4', black, 50, (button12.rect.x + 40), (button12.rect.y + 25))
text12 = Text('5', black, 50, (button13.rect.x + 40), (button13.rect.y + 25))
text13 = Text('6', black, 50, (button14.rect.x + 40), (button14.rect.y + 25))
text14 = Text('Fire!', black, 40, (button15.rect.x + 40), (button15.rect.y + 25))

rows = Text('Rows', white, 45, (x_list[1] + 10), (y_list[2] + 25))

columns = Text('Columns', white, 45, (x_list[1] + 40), (y_list[8] + 25))

done = False

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        # I am using this to see if the buttons are working
        # But every button is running this code not just the first one
        if button.click() == 1:
            print("Yay!")

        button_list.update()

    screen.fill(black)

    button_list.draw(screen)

    instructions.draw(screen)
    text.draw(screen)
    text1.draw(screen)
    text2.draw(screen)
    text3.draw(screen)
    text4.draw(screen)
    text5.draw(screen)
    text6.draw(screen)
    text7.draw(screen)
    text8.draw(screen)
    text9.draw(screen)
    text10.draw(screen)
    text11.draw(screen)
    text12.draw(screen)
    text13.draw(screen)
    text14.draw(screen)
    rows.draw(screen)
    columns.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(30)

pygame.quit()

screen0()
```

I have been stuck on this all day, I asked my teacher and he said that since I was doing something different that I had to figure out on my own, I even asked the tech guys at school and they didn't know :/ I have been looking through stack for about an hour now and nobody seems to be having the same issue as me... Please help and if there seems to be any indention issues with my code it is because I just copied and pasted it.

Comment: button.click() only runs the click funciton for the first button. So I'm not sure what your problem is? And btw you are doing it wrong. You should check for mouse click events in the event loop instead and only then check if any button was clicked.

Comment: I only have the one button.click() because when any button is pressed it runs that one, not just the first button. But I will do the check in the event loop instead and see if that works thank you :p

Comment: One more thing, right now your code don't check if an actual button is clicked. You only check if the mouse is clicked. Pygame rectangles have a collidepoint function which you can use to check if a point is inside the rectangle. Will come in handy for this.

Comment: Thank you for your help, when I saw that you had pointed that out I slapped myself on the forehead good and hard haha. I was able to fix it, thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

In your main program, write the 2 button functions (func1 (), func2 ()). Then add a variable to your button class 'self.action' and a method 'def setaction (function). When you create the button, call the method with the correct function: button.setaction (func1). Then on the clock code you can just so 'self.action' to call the appropriate function.